# insert text at cursor position in tinyMCE rich text editor

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I have few dropdown boxes which should insert dynamic text(according to the selection) at cursor position in tinyMCE rich text editor.

I found a lot of post related to above issue as bellow and it is not working currently with my code, also not giving any errors in the console as well.

```
tinyMCE.execInstanceCommand('text',"mceInsertContent",false,"This is the text to be inserted");
// here 'text' is id of textarea on which TinyMCE is rendered
```

I guess that when I click on dropdown boxes I loose the focus in text editor, but still I couldn't able to fix that.

Any help would appreciate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Need to use `execCommand` insted of `execInstanceCommand` as bellow,

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,"This is the text to be inserted");
```

Reason is I used tinyMCE old version(2X), So most of the commands not working with old API.